# Open Source SQL Static Code Analysis Tool

Tags: sql

Is there an Open-source SQL lint/static code analysis tool available that lets me specify custom rules?

I'm thinking of something akin to Food Critic https://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/ which allows me to use community rules or define my own.

Anyone aware of anything that allows me to do this for SQL?

I know Toad seems to allow this sort of function via it's rule sets. If it's the only option fair enough